# Seasonal adjustment in R

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I was sure the code below was working to seasonally adjust some data, but now it doesn't seem to be. I have probably done somthing daft, but can't work out what. Can  somebody please help?

data: https://github.com/Paul-Edward-C/cn-data

```
library(lubridate)

library(seasonal)

library(xts)


df <- read.csv(input_file, 
               sep = ",", 
               na.strings = "NA", 
               strip.white = TRUE, 
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
 
start_month <- month(df$Date[1])

start_year <- year(df$Date[1]) 

df_ts <- ts(df[-1], 
            start=c(start_year,start_month), 
            freq=12)


m <- seas(cbind(df_ts),
          xreg = genhol(cny, start = 0, end = 0, center = "calendar"),
          regression.aictest = "td",
          x11 = "",
          regression.usertype = "holiday"
)

df_sa <- as.xts(final(m))

names(df_sa)<-c(colnames(df)[-1])

index(df_sa) <- as.Date(index(df_sa), 
                        format="%b %Y")

write.csv(df_sa,output_file,
          row.names = index(df_sa))
```

Attaching package: ‘lubridate’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

```
date, intersect, setdiff, union
```

Loading required package: zoo

Attaching package: ‘zoo’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

```
as.Date, as.Date.numeric

> tail(df, n=20)


         Date National.retail.sales..CNY..Monthly
240 2019-12-01                            38,782.0
241 2020-01-01                            26,060.1
242 2020-02-01                            26,060.1
243 2020-03-01                            26,441.2
244 2020-04-01                            28,167.0
245 2020-05-01                            31,979.6
246 2020-06-01                            33,528.8
247 2020-07-01                            32,189.0
248 2020-08-01                            33,570.6
249 2020-09-01                            35,294.7
250 2020-10-01                            38,576.5
251 2020-11-01                            39,514.2
252 2020-12-01                            40,566.0
253 2021-01-01                            34,868.4
254 2021-02-01                            34,868.4
255 2021-03-01                            35,484.1
256 2021-04-01                            33,152.6
257 2021-05-01                            35,945.1
258 2021-06-01                            37,585.8
259 2021-07-01                            34,925.1
    National.retail.sales..retail.trade..CNY..Monthly National.retail.sales..catering..CNY..Monthly
240                                          33,855.8                                       4,930.0
241                                          23,967.6                                       2,097.5
242                                          23,967.6                                       2,097.5
243                                          24,613.9                                       1,832.2
244                                          25,869.5                                       2,306.6
245                                          28,971.0                                       3,014.5
246                                          30,272.5                                       3,263.6
247                                          28,918.1                                       3,282.1
248                                          29,951.3                                       3,619.3
249                                          31,579.5                                       3,715.1
250                                          34,204.1                                       4,372.3
251                                          34,534.4                                       4,979.7
252                                          35,616.3                                       4,949.7
253                                          31,325.7                                       3,542.7
254                                          31,325.7                                       3,542.7
255                                          31,973.5                                       3,510.5
256                                          29,775.8                                       3,376.9
257                                          32,128.8                                       3,816.3
258                                          33,663.0                                       3,922.8
259                                          31,173.7                                       3,751.4
]) 

    > tail(df_ts, n=20)
       National.retail.sales..CNY..Monthly National.retail.sales..retail.trade..CNY..Monthly
[240,]                                 165                                               117
[241,]                                  86                                                70
[242,]                                  86                                                70
[243,]                                  91                                                72
[244,]                                  96                                                82
[245,]                                 140                                                96
[246,]                                 149                                               103
[247,]                                 141                                                95
[248,]                                 150                                               102
[249,]                                 157                                               111
[250,]                                 164                                               118
[251,]                                 166                                               119
[252,]                                 196                                               120
[253,]                                 155                                               109
[254,]                                 155                                               109
[255,]                                 158                                               112
[256,]                                 146                                               101
[257,]                                 160                                               113
[258,]                                 162                                               116
[259,]                                 156                                               108
       National.retail.sales..catering..CNY..Monthly
[240,]                                           117
[241,]                                            31
[242,]                                            31
[243,]                                            13
[244,]                                            43
[245,]                                            68
[246,]                                            80
[247,]                                            81
[248,]                                            96
[249,]                                           100
[250,]                                           114
[251,]                                           119
[252,]                                           118
[253,]                                            94
[254,]                                            94
[255,]                                            92
[256,]                                            86
[257,]                                           104
[258,]                                           109
[259,]                                           102

+ )
Error: X-13 run failed

Errors:
- Adding AO2021.Apr exceeds the number of regression effects allowed in the model
  (80). Check the regression model, change the automatic outlier options, (e.g.
  method to ADDONE, raise the critical value, or change types to identify AOs only),
  or change the program limits (see Section 2.7 of the X-13ARIMA-SEATS Reference
  Manual). Program error(s) halt execution for
  /var/folders/jj/yp86y9gs6dd3fxn4j9mgyvk80000gn/T//Rtmptiuv5K/x131d895e37f09a/NationalretailsalesC.spc
- Adding AO2016.Nov exceeds the number of regression effects allowed in the model
  (80). Check the regression model, change the automatic outlier options, (e.g.
  method to ADDONE, raise the critical value, or change types to identify AOs only),
  or change the program limits (see Section 2.7 of the X-13ARIMA-SEATS Reference
  Manual). Program error(s) halt execution for
  /var/folders/jj/yp86y9gs6dd3fxn4j9mgyvk80000gn/T//Rtmptiuv5K/x131d895e37f09a/Nationalretailsalesr.spc
- Adding A
```

Answer (score 2):

Start a fresh session and read the raw version of the input file (not the URL given in the question but rather `u` shown below) into a zoo object `z` with yearmon class.  Because the numeric columns are defined with commas inside quotes they would normally be regarded as character so we define a class to convert them to numeric and specify that class in the `colClasses=` argument.  Now use`as.ts` will convert that to a ts object with frequency 12 usable.  Also, it seems that `seas` cannot distinguish between names that are the same in the first k characters for some k if passed a ts object.  Workarounds seem to be (1) make the names unique in the first k positions or  (2) convert the ts object to a list of ts objects.  We do the latter.

```
library(seasonal)
library(zoo)

u <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Paul-Edward-C/cn-data/main/cn_retail_nsa.csv"

setClass("num.comma")
setAs("character", "num.comma", function(from) as.numeric(gsub(",", "", from)))

nf <- count.fields(u, sep = ",")[1]
z <- read.csv.zoo(u, FUN = as.yearmon, colClasses = c(NA, rep("num.comma", nf-1)))
tt <- as.ts(z)
L <- Map(function(nm) tt[, nm], colnames(tt))  # convert to list

m <- seas(L,
          xreg = genhol(cny, start = 0, end = 0, center = "calendar"),
          regression.aictest = "td",
          x11 = "",
          regression.usertype = "holiday")
m
```

giving:

```
$National.retail.sales..CNY..Monthly

Call:
seas(x = L, xreg = genhol(cny, start = 0, end = 0, center = "calendar"), 
    regression.aictest = "td", x11 = "", regression.usertype = "holiday")

Coefficients:
             xreg         AO2001.Jan         AO2003.May         LS2004.Apr  
         0.003553           0.015152          -0.037941           0.020231  
       AO2005.Feb         AO2006.Jan         LS2007.Oct         LS2008.Dec  
         0.029072           0.026374           0.011891          -0.017261  
       LS2009.Feb         AO2010.Feb         AO2011.Jan         LS2019.Mar  
        -0.030569           0.042868           0.020402          -0.023052  
       LS2020.Jan         AO2020.Apr         LS2020.Apr         LS2020.Jul  
        -0.304376          -0.043385           0.159083           0.027020  
       LS2020.Sep         LS2021.Jan  MA-Nonseasonal-01     MA-Seasonal-12  
         0.032748          -0.056603           0.243636          -0.569232  


$National.retail.sales..retail.trade..CNY..Monthly

Call:
seas(x = L, xreg = genhol(cny, start = 0, end = 0, center = "calendar"), 
    regression.aictest = "td", x11 = "", regression.usertype = "holiday")

Coefficients:
             xreg         LS2011.Jan         LS2012.Apr         AO2016.Dec  
        0.0006381          0.0177392         -0.0074888          0.0045303  
       LS2018.May         LS2019.Jul         LS2020.Jan         LS2020.Mar  
       -0.0116767         -0.0205138         -0.2634525          0.0595134  
       LS2020.Apr         LS2020.May         AO2020.Jul         LS2020.Sep  
        0.0887770          0.0383029         -0.0169151          0.0246996  
       LS2021.Jan         LS2021.Mar         LS2021.Apr         AO2021.Jul  
       -0.0439001          0.0548717         -0.0323250         -0.0492754  
AR-Nonseasonal-01  AR-Nonseasonal-02  MA-Nonseasonal-01     MA-Seasonal-12  
       -0.5535409         -0.3663086         -0.4990941         -0.8305223  


$National.retail.sales..catering..CNY..Monthly

Call:
seas(x = L, xreg = genhol(cny, start = 0, end = 0, center = "calendar"), 
    regression.aictest = "td", x11 = "", regression.usertype = "holiday")

Coefficients:
             xreg         LS2011.Jan         LS2012.Jan         LS2020.Jan  
        3.435e-05          1.017e-01          5.798e-02         -6.519e-01  
       AO2020.Mar         LS2020.Mar         LS2020.May         AO2020.Jun  
       -2.638e-01          1.958e-01          1.542e-01          4.825e-02  
       LS2020.Jul         LS2020.Aug         LS2020.Sep         AO2020.Oct  
        9.758e-02          4.364e-02          4.313e-02          3.741e-02  
       LS2020.Nov         LS2021.Jan         LS2021.Mar  MA-Nonseasonal-01  
        2.555e-02         -1.296e-01          5.732e-02          2.241e-01
```

Comment: Thanks. The file input has three columns of different data, but while the code returns three series, two of those have the same output, "$NationalretailsalesC" and "$Nationalretailsalesc". How should that be resolved?

Comment: It seems you have found a bug in `seas`.  If the names of the ts object passed to `seas` are the same in the first k positions for some k (to be determined) then it will regard them as the same name effectively truncating them.   Have added additional discussion giving two workarounds and showing the simpler of the two in code.

Comment: Have added a github issue. https://github.com/christophsax/seasonal/issues/274

Comment: I tried changing the column titles do be more distinctive, and then the code in my original question works. Thanks for your help.